# Expected value of a number which digits are randomly generated - a possibly Markov chain problem

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

We start with a clean slate. At every step, we either attach one of two digits to the right of what we've accumulated ("1" - with probability 0.5, "2" - with probability 0.3) or we stop accumulating (with probability 0.2).

To illustrate: clean slate -> 1 (with probability 0.5) -> 12 (with probability 0.3) -> 121 (with probability 0.5) -> stop (with probability 0.2). Hence we acquire 121 with probability $0.5 * 0.3 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.015$. But what's the expected value of this number?

Comment: It is infinite, no?  Conditioned on getting a $k$ digit number, the expected value goes up by a factor of $10$ at each stage (roughly), but the probability of getting from stage to stage doesn't decrease that fast so the terms in the sum do not go to $0$.

Comment: What if we introduced (with some probability > 0) additional action of "idle", where you don't add any digits, but you don't stop either and just carry over what you have to the next step? Or another option, what if we introduced the rule that accumulating, say, three similar digits in a row amounts to a full stop? I suspect addition of idle won't change anything, but this similar digits-rule might. What's your intuition? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how idle changes anything.  As for increasing the probability of termination, well you have to cancel the growth.  As I remarked, the expected length grows by about a factor of $10$ so the probability of getting to the next length has got to decrease significantly faster than by a factor of $10$.  I don't think this particular trick does it, but you could play with the numbers.

Comment: Of course, I don't know where this comes from, but you could generate a decimal instead of an integer.  Thus you could get $.121$ in the example you gave.  Now the growth is simply an additive constant and the expectation is obviously finite.

Comment: ok, let's say it's decimal, not integer, with the same probabilities for "1", "2", and stop. How would you approach it?

Comment: Looks like $E[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n 10^{-n}] = 11/92$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest to first stick to the exercise **as it is given**. Then no, one does not attach decimals, but digits, to the right of the existing digits, to concoct a random **integer** $X$.

For every $n\geqslant1$, with probability $0.2\cdot(0.8)^n$, $X$ has exactly $n$ digits, each at least $1$, hence
$$
X\geqslant1+10+\cdots+10^{n-1}\geqslant10^{n-1}
$$
Thus,
$$
E(X)\geqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty10^{n-1}\cdot0.2\cdot(0.8)^n =0.02\sum_{n=1}^\infty8^n
$$
hence $E(X)$ is infinite.

If one decides after all to attach decimals, to the right of the existing decimals, to concoct a random **real number** $Y$ in $(0,1)$, then a similar reasoning applies but now,
$$
Y=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{D_n}{10^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{D_n}{10^n}\mathbf 1_{N\geqslant n}
$$
where each decimal $D_n$, present or not, has expectation
$$
E(D_n)=\frac{0.5\cdot1+0.3\cdot2}{0.5+0.3}=\frac{11}8
$$
and the number $N$ of decimals present in $Y$ is geometrically distributed with
$$
P(N\geqslant n)=(0.8)^n
$$
for every $n\geqslant0$. Thus,
$$
E(Y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E(D_n)}{10^n}P(N\geqslant n)
=\frac{11}8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{10^n}(0.8)^n
=\frac{11}8\frac{0.08}{1-0.08}=\frac{11}{92}
$$

Comment: Nice. Thank you. In the penultimate formula you meant to write $0.8^n$, not $0.9^n$.

Comment: Indeed I did. $ $